# Sparx Enterprise architect "Import DB Schema from ODBC" (Oracle 12c)

Tags: database, import, odbc, reverse-engineering, oracle12c

"Import DB Schema from ODBC" does not work with Oracle 12c. The result set (list of available objects) is empty. There is no error message. Accessing 11g databases works well. I'm using EA 9.3.935. 10.0.1009 also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with EA 11.1 latest version.  According to their release notes at http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/11/history.html#1107,

> ODBC import from Oracle 12C added

I have not tried EA11.1 yet but hoping that it works based on their release notes.

Comment: And I was starting to think there's a black magic taking place here. (EA10 + Oracle 12 ... only sequences showed up in the objects list.) Thank you.